# Canvas engine reverse sprite sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, canvasengine

I am using sprites for my game in Canvas-Engine and is there possible way to play animation backwards.
If I put frames from 10 to 0 it does not work.

`animations:{ 
    frames: [10, 0]
}`

Or is there way to mirror the image at each loop? But in some sprites its not a option.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to loop thought a spritesheet backwards or do you just want to go thought the spritesheet like normal but flip the sprite itself?

Comment: I don't want to flip it just run it from last frame to first.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what you want (you have to be *much* more specific in your question!)

But I did this:
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/qs37w/2/

It basically, animates from frame 0 to frame 10 then runs a switch to reverse it.

This runs as fast as the `requestAnimFrame` runs.

Comment: Nice, but I need it in this engine http://canvasengine.net/ To run from last to first frame. There are extension Animation, witch allows you to run sprite sheets and the frames variable contains array where `array[0] = FirstFrame` and `array[1] = LastFrame` I need to get `array[0] = LastFrame` and `array[1] = FirstFrame` Engien does not allow this kind of array.